# How to filter the values of two fields as one?

Tags: django-filter

How to aggregate the results of the two fields and show as one in django-filter?

Let's take, for example, such a model:

```
class Animal(object):
     LEGS_CHOICES = (2, 4, 8)
     legs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LEGS_CHOICES)

class Dog(Animal):
     pass

class Spider(Animal):
     pass
```

My django-filter filter class:

```
class AnimalFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    legs = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Animal.LEGS_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['legs']
```

I would like to filter this two models by the same fields and display them as one.

Using queryset I can do it like this:

```
Animal.objects.filter(Q(dog__legs = 4) | Q(spider__legs = 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own Filter

```
class MultiMultipleChoiceFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    """
    This filter preforms an OR query on the selected options for defined fields.
    """
    field_class = forms.MultipleChoiceField

    def __init__(self, fields, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MultiMultipleChoiceFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields = fields

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        value = value or ()
        if len(value) == len(self.field.choices):
            return qs
        q = Q()
        for v in value:
            for f in self.fields:
                q |= Q(**{f: v})
        return qs.filter(q).distinct()
```

Example of use. As a parameter, enter a list of fields.

```
class AnimalFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    legs = django_filters.MultiMultipleChoiceFilter(['dog__legs', 'spider__legs'], choices=Animal.LEGS_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['legs']
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks. However, in django-filter v.1.0.4, the form  label rendered as [invalid field] on the page, unless I included an explicit 'label' option to the field def in the FilterSet class.